# Angular1 meteor file upload not working

Tags: meteor, fs, angular-meteor

**Uncaught TypeError: data is not an Blob or File(…)UploadFS.Uploader @ ufs-uploader.js:47(anonymous function) @ methods.js:23reader.onload @ helpers.js:44**

After uploading meteor from 1.3 to 1.4 . File upload not working

methods.js

```
export function upload(dataUrl, name, resolve, reject) {
// convert to Blob
const blob = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);
blob.name = name;

// pick from an object only: name, type and size
const file = _.pick(blob, 'name', 'type', 'size');

// convert to ArrayBuffer
blobToArrayBuffer(blob, (data) => {
  const upload = new UploadFS.Uploader({
    data,
    file,
    store: ImagesStore,
    onError: reject,
    onComplete: resolve
  });

  upload.start();
}, reject);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you loaded the latest package from https://github.com/jalik/jalik-ufs - there were some breaking changes from Meteor 1.3 to 1.4:

**Breaking changes**

UploadFS.readAsArrayBuffer() is DEPRECATED

The method UploadFS.readAsArrayBuffer() is not available anymore, as uploads are using POST binary data, we don't need ArrayBuffer.